# create script to change the collation of a database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, collation

I have been working with a sql server 2012 database for a number of weeks and now I would like to change the collation of the database.

I thought it would be easy to just change its overall setting but unfortunately this is only applied to that point forth and not the current setup of database.

So I need to generate a script to change the collation of the database, including its existing content/structure.

Anyone can assist with automating this or any tips how might generate a script to achieve this?

Comment: I think I've got a script to do this at my office, but I won't be back there until Monday, if you're still stuck then I'll post it (if I can find it!)

Comment: Yes that would be excellent if you could post it, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just did a quick Google search and came up with these:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175835.aspx (not so helpful, only explains how to set the collation on a database, doesn't go into changing existing tables)

[Update Collation of all fields in database on the fly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878430/update-collation-of-all-fields-in-database-on-the-fly) (this is what you want, I think)