# how to change the collate to all the columns of the database?

Tags: sql-server, collation

I would like to change the collation of all the columns of all the tables of my database. In stack overflow, I have found this script: ([post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878430/update-collation-of-all-fields-in-database-on-the-fly))

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE [' + SYSOBJECTS.Name + '] ALTER COLUMN [' + SYSCOLUMNS.Name + '] ' +
SYSTYPES.name + 
    CASE systypes.NAME
    WHEN 'text' THEN ' '
    ELSE
    '(' + RTRIM(CASE SYSCOLUMNS.length
    WHEN -1 THEN 'MAX'
    ELSE CONVERT(CHAR,SYSCOLUMNS.length)
    END) + ') ' 
    END

    + ' ' + ' COLLATE Latin1_General__CI_AI ' + CASE ISNULLABLE WHEN 0 THEN 'NOT NULL' ELSE 'NULL' END
    FROM SYSCOLUMNS , SYSOBJECTS , SYSTYPES
    WHERE SYSCOLUMNS.ID = SYSOBJECTS.ID
    AND SYSOBJECTS.TYPE = 'U'
    AND SYSTYPES.Xtype = SYSCOLUMNS.xtype
    AND SYSCOLUMNS.COLLATION IS NOT NULL
    AND NOT ( sysobjects.NAME LIKE 'sys%' )
    AND NOT ( SYSTYPES.name LIKE 'sys%' )
    GO
```

However, when I see the collation of the columns I see that the collation is the old collation.

The actual collation is AS, so I can have "ANIMAL" and "ÁNIMAL". When I execute the script, I don't get any error. I think that I would get an error because the new collation is AI. So this makes me think that the script does nothing.

How can I change the collation of all the columns of all my tables in the database?

Thanks.

Comment: Slightly different answer when database is already built.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21149470/changing-collation-in-sql-server-2008-does-not-take-effect/21149593#21149593

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Try this one -

**Query:**

```
DECLARE @collate SYSNAME
SELECT @collate = 'Cyrillic_General_CS_AS'

SELECT 
      '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '].[' + o.name + '] -> ' + c.name
    , 'ALTER TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '].[' + o.name + ']
        ALTER COLUMN [' + c.name + '] ' +
        UPPER(t.name) + 
        CASE WHEN t.name NOT IN ('ntext', 'text') 
            THEN '(' + 
                CASE 
                    WHEN t.name IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar') AND c.max_length != -1 
                        THEN CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(10))
                    WHEN t.name IN ('char', 'varchar') AND c.max_length != -1 
                        THEN CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(10))
                    WHEN t.name IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'varchar') AND c.max_length = -1 
                        THEN 'MAX'
                    ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(10)) 
                END + ')' 
            ELSE '' 
        END + ' COLLATE ' + @collate + 
        CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 
            THEN ' NULL'
            ELSE ' NOT NULL'
        END
FROM sys.columns c
JOIN sys.objects o ON c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
JOIN sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id AND c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE t.name IN ('char', 'varchar', 'text', 'nvarchar', 'ntext', 'nchar')
    AND c.collation_name != @collate
    AND o.[type] = 'U'
```

**Output:**

```
-------------------------------------------------- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[dbo].[CategoryType] -> CategoryTypeCD          ALTER TABLE [dbo].[CategoryType] ALTER COLUMN [CategoryTypeCD] VARCHAR(20) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
[dbo].[Employee] -> TabelNumber                 ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Employee] ALTER COLUMN [TabelNumber] VARCHAR(12) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
[dbo].[Supplement] -> WorkFactorCD              ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Supplement] ALTER COLUMN [WorkFactorCD] VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
[dbo].[Surcharge] -> WorkFactorCD               ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Surcharge] ALTER COLUMN [WorkFactorCD] VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
[dbo].[Surcharge] -> Condition                  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Surcharge] ALTER COLUMN [Condition] NVARCHAR(MAX) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
[dbo].[WorkFactor] -> WorkFactorCD              ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WorkFactor] ALTER COLUMN [WorkFactorCD] VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
[dbo].[WorkFactor] -> Name                      ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WorkFactor] ALTER COLUMN [Name] NVARCHAR(200) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NOT NULL
[dbo].[WorkOut] -> WorkShiftCD                  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WorkOut] ALTER COLUMN [WorkShiftCD] NVARCHAR(40) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
[dbo].[WorkOut] -> AbsenceCode                  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WorkOut] ALTER COLUMN [AbsenceCode] VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
[dbo].[WorkOut] -> PaymentType                  ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WorkOut] ALTER COLUMN [PaymentType] CHAR(4) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL
```

Comment: I try to use the script and it seems to works, but do nothing. Then I try to use an alter table and I see that occurs an error because this field is used in an index. So I think that the script does not change any table because it occurs one or more errors.

Comment: @Álvaro García, this script is quite workable and I used it for several times. The idea was that you specify your COLLATE, copy the generated ALTER constructions, and execute them afterwords. There is no general solution to change columns collate with no problems. Such kind of issues are always involved in changing collates in a database, for instance, if the field is a foreign key.

Comment: The commands from the output work with one caveat.  You are missing a CASE statement for text data type.  Columns with text as the data type don't have a length applied to them.  So text(100) would be invalid.

Comment: This answer definitely works, as I've used it.  Thanks for the script, it saved me so much time.

Comment: Nice answer, but one small problem though. It didn't work for varchar(max) fields. It generated varchar(-1) and I had to manually edit those statements.

Comment: What if the column has index constraint or composite key constraint.Is it possible to add those conditions in to this query

Comment: This is a very elegant piece of code - very functional. Adding this to my toolbox

Answer (score 35):

I've pulled together the script below from various different sources that drop the dependencies updates the collation then recreate the dependant objects.  This solves the problem of updating the collation of columns that have dependencies (indexes, foreign key constraints, etc.)

```
/*******************************************************************************
*
* Created 2017-06-16 By Philip C
* Shared on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730114/how-to-change-the-collate-to-all-the-columns-of-the-database/44587493#44587493
*
* This script will check individual columns collations and check it against the
* database default collation, where they are different it will create the scripts
* required to drop all the objects dependant on the column, change the collation
* to the database default and then recreate the dependant objects.
* Some of the code has been reused from stuff found online the majority from 
* Jayakumaur R who created scripts to drop and recreate constraints
*
* Minor edit by Darren S to support SQL2019: Replaced AND ty.name !='sysname' with AND (ty.Name LIKE '%char%' OR ty.Name LIKE '%text%')
*********************************************************************************/

SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
GO
DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @IndexName VARCHAR(256);
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @is_unique VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @IndexTypeDesc VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @FileGroupName VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @is_disabled VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE @IndexOptions VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @IndexColumnId INT;
DECLARE @IsDescendingKey INT;
DECLARE @IsIncludedColumn INT;
DECLARE @TSQLScripCreationIndex VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @TSQLScripDisableIndex VARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Collation_objectid INT;
DECLARE @Collation_columnid INT;
DECLARE @Collation_constraint INT;
DECLARE @Collation_index INT;
DECLARE @Collation_foreign INT;
DECLARE @Collation_stats INT;
DECLARE @stats_id INT;
DECLARE @Collation_fkid INT;
DECLARE @Collation_unique INT;
DECLARE @DatabaseCollation VARCHAR(100);
CREATE TABLE #tempscriptstore (ScriptType VARCHAR(20),
script NVARCHAR(MAX));
SELECT @DatabaseCollation=collation_name
FROM sys.databases
WHERE database_id=DB_ID();

/************************************************************************************************************************************
*   Generates a list of all the columns where their collation doesn't match the database default and the depenmdancies they have.   *
************************************************************************************************************************************/
DECLARE collationfix CURSOR FOR
SELECT t.object_id, c.column_id, COUNT(kc.object_id) AS [has_key_constraint], COUNT(ic.index_id) AS [has_index], COUNT(fk.constraint_object_id) AS [has_foreign_key], COUNT(st.stats_id) AS [has_stats], COUNT(uq.object_id) AS [has_unique_constraint]
FROM sys.columns c
    INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id=t.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id=ty.system_type_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id=c.object_id AND ic.column_id=c.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.key_constraints kc ON kc.parent_object_id=c.object_id AND kc.unique_index_id=ic.index_id AND kc.type='PK'
    LEFT JOIN sys.key_constraints uq ON uq.parent_object_id=c.object_id AND uq.unique_index_id=ic.index_id AND uq.type='UQ'
    LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fk ON fk.referenced_object_id=c.object_id AND fk.constraint_column_id=c.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.stats_columns st ON st.object_id=c.object_id AND st.column_id=c.column_id AND st.stats_column_id !=1
WHERE t.is_ms_shipped=0 AND c.collation_name<>@DatabaseCollation AND (ty.Name LIKE '%char%' OR ty.Name LIKE '%text%')
GROUP BY t.object_id, c.column_id;
OPEN collationfix;
FETCH NEXT FROM collationfix
INTO @Collation_objectid, @Collation_columnid, @Collation_constraint, @Collation_index, @Collation_foreign, @Collation_stats, @Collation_unique;
WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)BEGIN

/************************************************************************************************************************************
*   Generates the code to update the columns colation                                                                               *
************************************************************************************************************************************/
  INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore(ScriptType, script)
  SELECT DISTINCT 'AlterCollation', 'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id)) + '.' +QUOTENAME(t.name)+' ALTER COLUMN '+QUOTENAME(c.name)+' '+CASE WHEN ty.name='ntext' THEN ty.name+' COLLATE '+@DatabaseCollation+' ' ELSE ty.name+'('+CASE WHEN c.max_length=-1 THEN 'MAX' ELSE CASE WHEN ty.name='nvarchar' THEN CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(20))ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(20))END END+') COLLATE '+@DatabaseCollation+' ' END+CASE WHEN c.is_nullable=1 THEN 'NULL;' ELSE 'NOT NULL;' END
  FROM sys.columns c
      INNER JOIN sys.tables t ON c.object_id=t.object_id
      INNER JOIN sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id=ty.system_type_id
      LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id=c.object_id AND ic.column_id=c.column_id
  WHERE t.is_ms_shipped=0 AND c.collation_name<>@DatabaseCollation AND (ty.Name LIKE '%char%' OR ty.Name LIKE '%text%') AND c.column_id=@Collation_columnid AND t.object_id=@Collation_objectid;

/************************************************************************************************************************************
*   If the column is in an index this creates the drop and recreate index script                                                    *
************************************************************************************************************************************/
  IF @Collation_index>0 BEGIN
    DECLARE CursorIndex CURSOR FOR
    SELECT DISTINCT SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) [schema_name], t.name, ix.name, CASE WHEN ix.is_unique=1 THEN 'UNIQUE ' ELSE '' END, ix.type_desc, CASE WHEN ix.is_padded=1 THEN 'PAD_INDEX = ON, ' ELSE 'PAD_INDEX = OFF, ' END+CASE WHEN ix.allow_page_locks=1 THEN 'ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, ' ELSE 'ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, ' END+CASE WHEN ix.allow_row_locks=1 THEN 'ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ' ELSE 'ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, ' END+CASE WHEN INDEXPROPERTY(t.object_id, ix.name, 'IsStatistics')=1 THEN 'STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, ' ELSE 'STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, ' END+CASE WHEN ix.ignore_dup_key=1 THEN 'IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, ' ELSE 'IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ' END+'SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, FILLFACTOR ='+CASE WHEN ix.fill_factor=0 THEN CAST(100 AS VARCHAR(3))ELSE CAST(ix.fill_factor AS VARCHAR(3))END AS IndexOptions, ix.is_disabled, FILEGROUP_NAME(ix.data_space_id) FileGroupName
    FROM sys.tables t
        JOIN sys.indexes ix ON t.object_id=ix.object_id
        JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id=t.object_id
        JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.index_id=ix.index_id AND ic.column_id=c.column_id AND ic.object_id=t.object_id
    WHERE ix.type>0 AND ix.is_primary_key=0 AND ix.is_unique_constraint=0
        --AND schema_name(tb.schema_id)= @SchemaName 
        --AND tb.name=@TableName
        AND t.is_ms_shipped=0 AND t.name<>'sysdiagrams' AND c.column_id=@Collation_columnid AND t.object_id=@Collation_objectid AND ic.column_id=@Collation_columnid
    ORDER BY SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id), t.name, ix.name;
    OPEN CursorIndex;
    FETCH NEXT FROM CursorIndex
    INTO @SchemaName, @TableName, @IndexName, @is_unique, @IndexTypeDesc, @IndexOptions, @is_disabled, @FileGroupName;
    WHILE(@@fetch_status=0)BEGIN
      DECLARE @IndexColumns VARCHAR(MAX);
      DECLARE @IncludedColumns VARCHAR(MAX);
      SET @IndexColumns='';
      SET @IncludedColumns='';
      DECLARE CursorIndexColumn CURSOR FOR
      SELECT col.name, ixc.is_descending_key, ixc.is_included_column
      FROM sys.tables tb
          INNER JOIN sys.indexes ix ON tb.object_id=ix.object_id
          INNER JOIN sys.index_columns ixc ON ix.object_id=ixc.object_id AND ix.index_id=ixc.index_id
          INNER JOIN sys.columns col ON ixc.object_id=col.object_id AND ixc.column_id=col.column_id
      WHERE ix.type>0 AND(ix.is_primary_key=0 OR ix.is_unique_constraint=0)AND SCHEMA_NAME(tb.schema_id)=@SchemaName AND tb.name=@TableName AND ix.name=@IndexName
      ORDER BY ixc.index_column_id;
      OPEN CursorIndexColumn;
      FETCH NEXT FROM CursorIndexColumn
      INTO @ColumnName, @IsDescendingKey, @IsIncludedColumn;
      WHILE(@@fetch_status=0)BEGIN
        IF @IsIncludedColumn=0
          SET @IndexColumns=@IndexColumns+@ColumnName+CASE WHEN @IsDescendingKey=1 THEN ' DESC, ' ELSE ' ASC, ' END;
        ELSE SET @IncludedColumns=@IncludedColumns+@ColumnName+', ';
        FETCH NEXT FROM CursorIndexColumn
        INTO @ColumnName, @IsDescendingKey, @IsIncludedColumn;
      END;
      CLOSE CursorIndexColumn;
      DEALLOCATE CursorIndexColumn;
      SET @IndexColumns=SUBSTRING(@IndexColumns, 1, LEN(@IndexColumns)-1);
      SET @IncludedColumns=CASE WHEN LEN(@IncludedColumns)>0 THEN SUBSTRING(@IncludedColumns, 1, LEN(@IncludedColumns)-1)ELSE '' END;
      --  print @IndexColumns
      --  print @IncludedColumns
      INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore(ScriptType, script)
      SELECT 'DropIndex', 'DROP INDEX '+QUOTENAME(@SchemaName)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@TableName)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@IndexName)+';';
      INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore(ScriptType, script)
      SELECT 'CreateIndex', 'CREATE '+@is_unique+@IndexTypeDesc+' INDEX '+QUOTENAME(@IndexName)+' ON '+QUOTENAME(@SchemaName)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@TableName)+'('+@IndexColumns+') '+CASE WHEN LEN(@IncludedColumns)>0 THEN CHAR(13)+'INCLUDE ('+@IncludedColumns+')' ELSE '' END+CHAR(13)+'WITH ('+@IndexOptions+') ON '+QUOTENAME(@FileGroupName)+';';
      IF @is_disabled=1
        INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore(ScriptType, script)
        SELECT 'DisableIndex', 'ALTER INDEX '+QUOTENAME(@IndexName)+' ON '+QUOTENAME(@SchemaName)+'.'+QUOTENAME(@TableName)+' DISABLE;';
      FETCH NEXT FROM CursorIndex
      INTO @SchemaName, @TableName, @IndexName, @is_unique, @IndexTypeDesc, @IndexOptions, @is_disabled, @FileGroupName;
    END;
    CLOSE CursorIndex;
    DEALLOCATE CursorIndex;
  END;

/************************************************************************************************************************************
*   If the column has a primary key constraint this creates the drop and recreate constraint script                                 *
*   this has been taken and adapted from a script found online created by Jayakumaur R                                              *
************************************************************************************************************************************/
  IF @Collation_constraint>0 BEGIN
    -------------------------------------------------
    --ALTER TABLE DROP PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT Queries
    -------------------------------------------------
    INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore(ScriptType, script)
    SELECT DISTINCT 'DropPrimaryKey', 'ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))+'.'+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id))+' DROP CONSTRAINT '+QUOTENAME(name)
    FROM sys.key_constraints skc
    WHERE type='PK' AND parent_object_id=@Collation_objectid;

    ---------------------------------------------------
    --ALTER TABLE CREATE PRIMARY KEY CONSTRAINT Queries
    ---------------------------------------------------
    SELECT QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))+'.'+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) AS pk_table, --PK table name
      skc.object_id AS constid, QUOTENAME(skc.name) AS constraint_name, --PK name
      QUOTENAME(iskcu.COLUMN_NAME)+CASE WHEN sic.is_descending_key=1 THEN ' DESC' ELSE ' ASC' END AS pk_col, iskcu.ORDINAL_POSITION, CASE WHEN unique_index_id=1 THEN 'UNIQUE' ELSE '' END AS index_unique_type, si.name AS index_name, si.type_desc AS index_type, QUOTENAME(fg.name) AS filegroup_name, 'WITH('+' PAD_INDEX = '+CASE WHEN si.is_padded=0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE 'ON' END+','+' IGNORE_DUP_KEY = '+CASE WHEN si.ignore_dup_key=0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE 'ON' END+','+' ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = '+CASE WHEN si.allow_row_locks=0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE 'ON' END+','+' ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = '+CASE WHEN si.allow_page_locks=0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE 'ON' END+')' AS index_property
    --,*
    INTO #temp_pk
    FROM sys.key_constraints skc
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE iskcu ON skc.name=iskcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes si ON si.object_id=skc.parent_object_id AND si.is_primary_key=1
        INNER JOIN sys.index_columns sic ON si.object_id=sic.object_id AND si.index_id=sic.index_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON sic.object_id=c.object_id AND sic.column_id=c.column_id
        INNER JOIN sys.filegroups fg ON si.data_space_id=fg.data_space_id
    WHERE skc.type='PK' AND iskcu.COLUMN_NAME=c.name AND skc.parent_object_id=@Collation_objectid
    ORDER BY skc.parent_object_id, skc.name, ORDINAL_POSITION;
    WITH cte AS (SELECT pk_table, constraint_name, index_type, SUBSTRING((SELECT ','+pk_col FROM #temp_pk WHERE constid=t.constid FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 99999) AS pk_col_list, index_unique_type, filegroup_name, index_property
            FROM #temp_pk t)
    --forming the ADD CONSTRAINT query
    INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore(ScriptType, script)
    SELECT DISTINCT 'AddPrimaryKey', 'ALTER TABLE '+pk_table+' ADD CONSTRAINT '+constraint_name+' PRIMARY KEY '+CAST(index_type COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS VARCHAR(100))+' ('+pk_col_list+')'+index_property+' ON '+filegroup_name+''
    FROM cte;

    --dropping the temp tables
    DROP TABLE #temp_pk;
  END;

/************************************************************************************************************************************
*   If the column has a foreign key constraint this creates the drop and recreate constraint script                                 *
*   this has been taken and adapted from a script found online cretaed by Jayakumaur R                                              *
************************************************************************************************************************************/
  IF @Collation_foreign>0 BEGIN
    DECLARE foreignkeycursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT constraint_object_id
    FROM sys.foreign_key_columns
    WHERE referenced_object_id=@Collation_objectid AND referenced_column_id=@Collation_columnid;
    OPEN foreignkeycursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM foreignkeycursor
    INTO @Collation_fkid;
    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)BEGIN

      ---------------------------------------------
      --ALTER TABLE DROP FOREIGN CONSTRAINT Queries
      ---------------------------------------------
      INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore(ScriptType, script)
      SELECT DISTINCT 'DropForeignKey', 'ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkeyid))+'.'+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkeyid))+' DROP CONSTRAINT '+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(constid))
      FROM sys.sysforeignkeys sfk
      WHERE sfk.constid=@Collation_fkid;

      ------------------------------------------------
      --ALTER TABLE CREATE FOREIGN CONSTRAINT Queries
      ------------------------------------------------

      --Obtaining the necessary info from the sys tables
      SELECT constid, QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(constid)) AS constraint_name, CASE WHEN fk.is_not_trusted=1 THEN 'WITH NOCHECK' ELSE 'WITH CHECK' END AS trusted_status, QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fkeyid))+'.'+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fkeyid)) AS fk_table, QUOTENAME(c1.name) AS fk_col, QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(rkeyid))+'.'+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(rkeyid)) AS rk_table, QUOTENAME(c2.name) AS rk_col, CASE WHEN fk.delete_referential_action=1 AND fk.delete_referential_action_desc='CASCADE' THEN 'ON DELETE CASCADE ' ELSE '' END AS delete_cascade, CASE WHEN fk.update_referential_action=1 AND fk.update_referential_action_desc='CASCADE' THEN 'ON UPDATE CASCADE ' ELSE '' END AS update_cascade, CASE WHEN fk.is_disabled=1 THEN 'NOCHECK' ELSE 'CHECK' END AS check_status
      --,sysfk.*,fk.* 
      INTO #temp_fk
      FROM sys.sysforeignkeys sysfk
          INNER JOIN sys.foreign_keys fk ON sysfk.constid=fk.object_id
          INNER JOIN sys.columns c1 ON sysfk.fkeyid=c1.object_id AND sysfk.fkey=c1.column_id
          INNER JOIN sys.columns c2 ON sysfk.rkeyid=c2.object_id AND sysfk.rkey=c2.column_id
      WHERE sysfk.constid=@Collation_fkid
      ORDER BY constid, sysfk.keyno

      --building the column list for foreign/primary key tables
      ;
      WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT constraint_name, trusted_status, fk_table, SUBSTRING((SELECT ','+fk_col FROM #temp_fk WHERE constid=c.constid FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 99999) AS fk_col_list, rk_table, SUBSTRING((SELECT ','+rk_col FROM #temp_fk WHERE constid=c.constid FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 99999) AS rk_col_list, check_status, delete_cascade, update_cascade
              FROM #temp_fk c)
      --forming the ADD CONSTRAINT query
      INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore(ScriptType, script)
      SELECT DISTINCT 'AddForeignKey', 'ALTER TABLE '+fk_table+' '+trusted_status+' ADD CONSTRAINT '+constraint_name+' FOREIGN KEY('+fk_col_list+') REFERENCES '+rk_table+'('+rk_col_list+')'+' '+delete_cascade+update_cascade+';'+' ALTER TABLE '+fk_table+' '+check_status+' CONSTRAINT '+constraint_name
      FROM cte;

      --dropping the temp tables
      DROP TABLE #temp_fk;
      FETCH NEXT FROM foreignkeycursor
      INTO @Collation_fkid;
    END;
    CLOSE foreignkeycursor;
    DEALLOCATE foreignkeycursor;
  END;

/************************************************************************************************************************************
*   If the column has statistics that aren't part of an index this creates the drop and recreate scripts                                *
************************************************************************************************************************************/
  IF @Collation_stats>0 AND @Collation_index=0 BEGIN
    DECLARE stats_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT sc.stats_id
    FROM sys.stats_columns sc
        JOIN sys.stats s ON s.object_id=sc.object_id AND s.stats_id=sc.stats_id AND s.user_created=1
    WHERE sc.object_id=@Collation_objectid AND sc.column_id=@Collation_columnid;
    OPEN stats_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM stats_cursor
    INTO @stats_id;
    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)BEGIN
      --Create DROP Statistics Statement
      INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore(ScriptType, script)
      SELECT 'DropStatistics', 'DROP STATISTICS '+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(s.object_id))+'.'+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id))+'.'+QUOTENAME(s.name)
      FROM sys.stats s
      WHERE s.object_id=@Collation_objectid AND s.stats_id=@stats_id;

      --Building the CREATE statistics statement

      --Obtaining all the information
      SELECT QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(sc.object_id))+'.'+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(sc.object_id)) AS st_table, QUOTENAME(s.name) AS st_name, QUOTENAME(c.name) AS st_column, sc.object_id, sc.stats_id, sc.stats_column_id
      INTO #temp_stats
      FROM sys.stats_columns sc
          JOIN sys.stats s ON s.stats_id=sc.stats_id AND s.object_id=sc.object_id
          JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id=sc.object_id AND c.column_id=sc.column_id
      WHERE sc.object_id=@Collation_objectid AND sc.stats_id=@stats_id;
      WITH cte AS (SELECT DISTINCT st_table, st_name, SUBSTRING((SELECT ','+st_column
                                      FROM #temp_stats
                                      WHERE stats_id=ts.stats_id
                                      ORDER BY stats_column_id ASC
                                    FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 99999) AS st_col_list
              FROM #temp_stats ts)
      --Constructing the statement
      INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore(ScriptType, script)
      SELECT 'AddStatistics', 'CREATE STATISTICS '+cte.st_name+' ON '+cte.st_table+'('+cte.st_col_list+')'
      FROM cte;
      DROP TABLE #temp_stats;
      FETCH NEXT FROM stats_cursor
      INTO @stats_id;
    END;
    CLOSE stats_cursor;
    DEALLOCATE stats_cursor;
  END;

/************************************************************************************************************************************
*   If the column has a unique constraint this creates the drop and recreate scripts                                                *
************************************************************************************************************************************/
  IF @Collation_unique>0 BEGIN

    -------------------------------------------------
    --ALTER TABLE DROP UNIQUE CONSTRAINT Queries
    -------------------------------------------------
    INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore(ScriptType, script)
    SELECT DISTINCT 'DropUniqueKey', 'ALTER TABLE '+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))+'.'+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id))+' DROP CONSTRAINT '+QUOTENAME(name)
    FROM sys.key_constraints skc
        JOIN sys.index_columns ic ON ic.object_id=skc.parent_object_id AND ic.index_id=skc.unique_index_id
    WHERE type='UQ' AND parent_object_id=@Collation_objectid AND ic.column_id=@Collation_columnid;

    ---------------------------------------------------
    --ALTER TABLE CREATE UNIQUE CONSTRAINT Queries
    ---------------------------------------------------
    SELECT QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(parent_object_id))+'.'+QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id)) AS uq_table, --PK table name
      skc.object_id AS constid, QUOTENAME(skc.name) AS constraint_name, --PK name
      QUOTENAME(iskcu.COLUMN_NAME)+CASE WHEN sic.is_descending_key=1 THEN ' DESC' ELSE ' ASC' END AS uq_col, iskcu.ORDINAL_POSITION, CASE WHEN unique_index_id=1 THEN 'UNIQUE' ELSE '' END AS index_unique_type, si.name AS index_name, si.type_desc AS index_type, QUOTENAME(fg.name) AS filegroup_name, 'WITH('+' PAD_INDEX = '+CASE WHEN si.is_padded=0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE 'ON' END+','+' IGNORE_DUP_KEY = '+CASE WHEN si.ignore_dup_key=0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE 'ON' END+','+' ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = '+CASE WHEN si.allow_row_locks=0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE 'ON' END+','+' ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = '+CASE WHEN si.allow_page_locks=0 THEN 'OFF' ELSE 'ON' END+')' AS index_property
    --,*
    INTO #temp_uq
    FROM sys.key_constraints skc
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE iskcu ON skc.name=iskcu.CONSTRAINT_NAME
        INNER JOIN sys.indexes si ON si.object_id=skc.parent_object_id AND si.is_unique=1
        INNER JOIN sys.index_columns sic ON si.object_id=sic.object_id AND si.index_id=sic.index_id
        INNER JOIN sys.columns c ON sic.object_id=c.object_id AND sic.column_id=c.column_id
        INNER JOIN sys.filegroups fg ON si.data_space_id=fg.data_space_id
    WHERE skc.type='UQ' AND iskcu.COLUMN_NAME=c.name AND skc.parent_object_id=@Collation_objectid AND c.column_id=@Collation_columnid
    ORDER BY skc.parent_object_id, skc.name, ORDINAL_POSITION;
    WITH cte AS (SELECT uq_table, constraint_name, index_type, SUBSTRING((SELECT ','+uq_col FROM #temp_uq WHERE constid=t.constid FOR XML PATH('')), 2, 99999) AS uq_col_list, index_unique_type, filegroup_name, index_property
            FROM #temp_uq t)
    --forming the ADD CONSTRAINT query
    INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore(ScriptType, script)
    SELECT DISTINCT 'AddUniqueKey', 'ALTER TABLE '+uq_table+' ADD CONSTRAINT '+constraint_name+' UNIQUE '+CAST(index_type COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT AS VARCHAR(100))+' ('+uq_col_list+')'+index_property+' ON '+filegroup_name+''
    FROM cte;

    --dropping the temp tables
    DROP TABLE #temp_uq;
  END;
  FETCH NEXT FROM collationfix
  INTO @Collation_objectid, @Collation_columnid, @Collation_constraint, @Collation_index, @Collation_foreign, @Collation_stats, @Collation_unique;
END;
CLOSE collationfix;
DEALLOCATE collationfix;

/************************************************************************************************************************************
*   Returns all the created scripts in the correct order for running                                                                *
************************************************************************************************************************************/
SELECT DISTINCT script, CASE WHEN ScriptType='DropForeignKey' THEN 1
            WHEN ScriptType='DropPrimaryKey' THEN 2
            WHEN ScriptType='DropUniqueKey' THEN 3
            WHEN ScriptType='DropIndex' THEN 4
            WHEN ScriptType='DropStatistics' THEN 5
            WHEN ScriptType='AlterCollation' THEN 6
            WHEN ScriptType='CreateIndex' THEN 7
            WHEN ScriptType='DisableIndex' THEN 8
            WHEN ScriptType='AddStatistics' THEN 9
            WHEN ScriptType='AddUniqueKey' THEN 10
            WHEN ScriptType='AddPrimaryKey' THEN 11
            WHEN ScriptType='AddForeignKey' THEN 12 ELSE 99 END AS [exec_order]
FROM #tempscriptstore
WHERE script !=''
ORDER BY exec_order ASC;
DROP TABLE #tempscriptstore;
```

Comment: You sir, are the MVP!

Comment: This should be the top answer

Comment: I was having some issue because the query was trying to change the collation of non text columns, so I've added a ` AND c.collation_name IS NOT NULL` and the end of the `WHERE` clausule of first cursor and it worked fine.

Comment: i don't have words to explain how much i'm thank you!.

Comment: Script is cool, but there few mistakes:  

* Computed columns are not processed,  
* text type is processed incorrectly, size is added to text column but text does not have size

Comment: Nice script but for AlterCollation statements the schema name is missing.

Comment: Nice, I needed to edit the above to replace AND ty.name !='sysname' with AND (ty.Name LIKE '%char%' OR ty.Name LIKE '%text%') as it was picking up system stuff on SQL2019

Comment: I was hopeful but tried this script to change collation on an Azure Devops Server 2020 collection DB (lot of objects) threw this error: Msg 220, Level 16, State 1, Line 94
Arithmetic overflow error for data type smallint, value = 65603.   The line is "OPEN CursorIndex;"  any ideas? Thanks

Comment: A few other added fixes to this script. Bas Roovers added it in a GitHub. Saved me alot of headache! https://github.com/theelog/sysops-scripts/blob/master/sql/change_collation.sql . I still had a few exceptions with Foreign keys depending on Primary keys to be dropped but as these were a few, i did them manually.

Answer (score 8):

I'm posting an edit to the above answer, which addresses char and varchar lengths, as my previous edit looks like it's being rejected.

```
DECLARE @collate SYSNAME
SELECT @collate = 'Cyrillic_General_CS_AS'

SELECT 
  '[' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '].[' + o.name + '] -> ' + c.name
, 'ALTER TABLE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(o.[schema_id]) + '].[' + o.name + ']
    ALTER COLUMN [' + c.name + '] ' +
    UPPER(t.name) + 
    CASE WHEN t.name NOT IN ('ntext', 'text') 
        THEN '(' + 
            CASE 
                WHEN t.name IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar') AND c.max_length != -1 
                    THEN CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(10))
                WHEN t.name IN ('char', 'varchar') AND c.max_length != -1 
                    THEN CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(10))
                WHEN t.name IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'varchar') AND c.max_length = -1 
                    THEN 'MAX'
                ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS VARCHAR(10)) 
            END + ')' 
        ELSE '' 
    END + ' COLLATE ' + @collate + 
    CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 
        THEN ' NULL'
        ELSE ' NOT NULL'
    END
FROM sys.columns c WITH(NOLOCK)
    JOIN sys.objects o WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.[object_id] = o.[object_id]
    JOIN sys.types t WITH(NOLOCK) ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id AND c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
WHERE t.name IN ('char', 'varchar', 'text', 'nvarchar', 'ntext', 'nchar')
    AND c.collation_name != @collate
    AND o.[type] = 'U'
```

Answer (score 3):

While none of the other approaches worked for me, [this article by Douglas P. Castilho](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3519/changing-sql-server-collation-after-installation/) provided me a complete solution. I am sharing it in case it helps anyone.

1. Create backups of all databases.
2. Stop the SQL Server Services on the server.
3. Open a Command Prompt and Navigate to the Binn Directory, like

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Binn

4. Execute the command below to apply a new collation.

> sqlservr -m -T4022 -T3659 -q"[Enter Collation Name]"

5. Start SQL Server Service again.

That's it.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks all for suggestion, it help me lot while migrating my database from SQL Server 2008 R2 to 2014

**NOTE:** Some of the resulted query have invalid VARCHAR(-), I changed it into VARCHAR(MAX), and it is working fine.

Steps to change Collation:

1. Run above query and get Alter table query
2. Drop all indexes of tables and Table valued functions
3. Run the generated query of step 1
4. Create indexes of tables and table valued functions.

Answer (score 1):

Before doing this operation please read this article first.
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3221/how-to-change-the-collation-of-a-sql-server-column/

After reading above article and make sure you removed below references from your database.

- A computed column
- An index Distribution statistics, either generated
  automatically or by the CREATE STATISTICS statement
- A CHECK constraint
- A FOREIGN KEY constraint

**Hit the below script on your database after that don't forget to change also database collation.**

```
DECLARE @collate nvarchar(100);
DECLARE @schema_name nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @table_name nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @column_name nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @column_id int;
DECLARE @data_type nvarchar(255);
DECLARE @max_length int;
DECLARE @is_nullable bit; 
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max);
DECLARE @sql_column nvarchar(max);

SET @collate = 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS';


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

    DECLARE local_change_cursor CURSOR FOR

    SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(t.schema_id) schemaname,
          t.name table_name
        , c.name column_name
        , s.Name data_type
        , c.max_length
        , c.is_nullable
        , c.column_id 
  FROM sys.tables t INNER JOIN
       sys.columns c ON c.object_id=t.object_id INNER JOIN
       sys.types s ON s.user_type_id=c.user_type_id
 WHERE 
 (c.collation_name LIKE 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1254_CI_AS' OR c.collation_name LIKE 'Turkish_CI_AS')  AND 
 t.type like 'U'
   AND t.name not like 'spt%'
   AND t.name not like 'MSrep%'
   AND c.collation_name is NOT NULL
order by schemaname 

    OPEN local_change_cursor
    FETCH NEXT FROM local_change_cursor
    INTO @schema_name,@table_name, @column_name, @data_type, @max_length,@is_nullable, @column_id

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        DECLARE @nullable nvarchar(255),
                @length   varchar(10);

        IF @is_nullable = 0
            BEGIN
                SET @nullable = ' NOT NULL';
            END
        ELSE 
            BEGIN
                SET @nullable = ' NULL';
            END

            IF @data_type IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar') AND @max_length != -1 
                BEGIN
                    SET @length= CAST(@max_length / 2 AS VARCHAR(10));
                END 
            ELSE IF @data_type IN ('char', 'varchar') AND @max_length != -1 
                BEGIN
                    SET @length= CAST(@max_length AS VARCHAR(10));
                END 
            ELSE IF @data_type IN ('nchar', 'nvarchar', 'char', 'varchar') AND @max_length = -1 
                BEGIN
                    SET @length= 'MAX';
                END 
            ELSE 
                BEGIN
                    SET @length= CAST(@max_length AS VARCHAR(10));
                END

        BEGIN TRY
            IF @schema_name <> 'dbo'
                BEGIN
                    SET @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ['+ @schema_name +'].[' + @table_name + '] ALTER COLUMN [' + @column_name + '] ' + @data_type + '(' + @length + ') COLLATE ' + @collate + ''+ @nullable+' '
                    PRINT @sql
                    EXEC sp_executesql @sql
                END
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
            PRINT 'ERROR: Some index or constraint rely on the column' + @column_name + '. No conversion possible.'
            PRINT @sql
        END CATCH

        FETCH NEXT FROM local_change_cursor
        INTO @schema_name,@table_name, @column_name, @data_type, @max_length,@is_nullable, @column_id

    END

    CLOSE local_change_cursor
    DEALLOCATE local_change_cursor
END

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for this solution who is using PHPMyAdmin, there is an option at the bottom of the "Database Operations" tab (click on a db first, then "operations" tab on the top toolbar); scroll down to the collation box, select a collation, check the two checkboxes(one appears when the first is checked) :

- Change all tables collations
- Change all tables columns collations

Appears to basically run a script like the ones posted; the console shows the final command executed:

```
ALTER TABLE `DB_NAME`.`LAST_TABLE_IN_DB`DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a simpler approach is using PowerShell and SMO, e.g.:

```
$db = Get-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance MyServer -Database MyDb
$db.Tables  | % { 
  $t = $_
  $t | % {
    If ($_.Collation -eq 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS') {
      $_.Collation = 'Latin1_General_CI_AS'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Part One

> Note: This is not my solution, it is a compilation of comments posts that worked for me from this page https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2019/01/collation-change-script/.

```
/*******************************************************************************
*
* Created 2017-06-16 By Philip C
*
* This script will check individual columns collations and check it against the
* database default collation, where they are different it will create the scripts
* required to drop all the objects dependant on the column, change the collation
* to the database default and then recreate the dependant objects.
* Some of the code has been reused from stuff found online the majority from
* Jayakumaur R who created scripts to drop and recreate constraints
*
*
* Modified 2019-01-11 by Hugo Kornelis
*
* Removed double checking of recreated constraints
* Modified the order of the output to minimize number of index rebuilds (assuming primary key is most often clsutered index)
* Fixed a bug caused by unique constraints overlapping the primary key constraint
* Fixed a bug in detection of foreign key constraints to drop and recreate
* Fixed bugs with recreating multi-column UNIQUE constraints
*
* Modified 2019-08-12 by Walter Charrière
*
* Add drop and create default constraints
* Fixed bug with text columns adding length
* Add Where calusule for filtered indexes
*
* Modified 2019-12-19 by Damon Clark
*
* Added fix from Erland for doubling length of nchar columns
* Added quoting of column names in create index statements (for reserved words)
*
* Modified 2022-11-14 by Fernan2
* Added Darren Rhymer check constraint drop and create
* 
************************************************************************************/

SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF;
    GO
    
    -- Declare variables
    DECLARE @SchemaName sysname,
    @TableName sysname,
    @IndexName sysname,
    @ColumnName sysname,
    @index_id int,
    @is_unique nvarchar(100),
    @IndexTypeDesc nvarchar(100),
    @FileGroupName sysname,
    @is_disabled nvarchar(100),
    @IndexOptions nvarchar(MAX),
    @IndexColumnId int,
    @IsDescendingKey int,
    @IsIncludedColumn int,
    @TSQLScripCreationIndex nvarchar(MAX),
    @TSQLScripDisableIndex nvarchar(MAX),
    @object_id int,
    @has_key_constraint int,
    @has_index int,
    @has_foreign_key int,
    @has_stats int,
    @stats_id int,
    @FK_objectid int,
    @FK_name sysname,
    @UQ_objectid int,
    @UQ_name sysname,
    @UQ_index_id int,
    @has_unique_constraint int,
    @has_default_constraint int,
    @has_check_constraint int,
    @DatabaseCollation sysname,
    @IndexColumns nvarchar(MAX),
    @IncludedColumns nvarchar(MAX),
    @filter_definition nvarchar(MAX);
    
    -- Temporary table for generated script
    CREATE TABLE #tempscriptstore
    (ScriptType varchar(20),
    script nvarchar(MAX));
    
    -- Get dataabse default collation
    SELECT @DatabaseCollation = collation_name
    FROM sys.databases
    WHERE database_id = DB_ID();
    
    /************************************************************************************************************************************
    * Iterate over all the tables that have at least one colmun where collation doesn't match the database default. *
    * Also checks for PRIMARY KEY, UNIQUE, and (referencing) FOREIGN KEY constraints, indexes, and manually created statistics. *
    * (Note that the counts are not accurate counts due to duplication, these should only be tested for zero or non-zero) *
    ************************************************************************************************************************************/
    DECLARE collationfix CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY STATIC FOR
    SELECT t.object_id,
    OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id) AS schemaname,
    OBJECT_NAME(t.object_id) AS tablename,
    COUNT(kc.object_id) AS has_key_constraint,
    COUNT(ic.index_id) AS has_index,
    COUNT(fk.constraint_object_id) AS has_foreign_key,
    COUNT(st.stats_id) AS has_stats,
    COUNT(uq.object_id) AS has_unique_constraint,
    COUNT(dc.object_id) AS has_default_constraint,
    count(cc.object_id) as has_check_constraint
    FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c
    ON c.object_id = t.object_id
    AND c.collation_name <> @DatabaseCollation -- Table needs to have columns with “wrong” collation
    INNER JOIN sys.types AS ty
    ON ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
    AND ty.name <> N'sysname' -- Exclusion retained from Philip C's original script
    LEFT JOIN sys.index_columns AS ic -- Find indexes on any of the affected columns
    ON ic.object_id = c.object_id
    AND ic.column_id = c.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.key_constraints AS kc -- Find primary key constraints related to an affected index
    ON kc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
    AND kc.unique_index_id = ic.index_id
    AND kc.type = 'PK'
    LEFT JOIN sys.key_constraints AS uq -- Find unique constraints related to an affected index
    ON uq.parent_object_id = c.object_id
    AND uq.unique_index_id = ic.index_id
    AND uq.type = 'UQ'
    LEFT JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns AS fk -- Find foreign key constraints on any of the affected columns
    ON fk.parent_object_id = c.object_id
    AND fk.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.stats_columns AS st -- Find statistics on any of the affected columns
    ON st.object_id = c.object_id
    AND st.column_id = c.column_id
    AND st.stats_column_id <> 1 -- Retained from Philip C's original script, no idea why this is in the query
    LEFT JOIN sys.default_constraints AS dc -- Find default constraints on any of the affected columns
    ON dc.object_id = c.default_object_id
    AND dc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.check_constraints AS cc -- Find check_constraints on any of the affected columns
    ON cc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
    AND cc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
    
    WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0 -- Exclude Microsoft-shipped tables
    
    GROUP BY t.object_id
    --order by 3
    
    OPEN collationfix;
    FETCH NEXT FROM collationfix
    INTO @object_id,
    @SchemaName,
    @TableName,
    @has_key_constraint,
    @has_index,
    @has_foreign_key,
    @has_stats,
    @has_unique_constraint,
    @has_default_constraint,
    @has_check_constraint;
    
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN;
    
    /************************************************************************************************************************************
    *   Generates the code to update the colation for all affected columns in the table                                                 *
    ************************************************************************************************************************************/
    INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                  script)
    SELECT      'AlterCollation',
                N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' ALTER COLUMN '
                + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' '
                + CASE WHEN ty.name = N'ntext' or ty.name = N'text'
                           THEN ty.name + N' COLLATE ' + @DatabaseCollation + ' '
                       ELSE ty.name + N'(' + CASE WHEN c.max_length = -1
                                                      THEN N'MAX'
                                                  ELSE CASE WHEN ty.name IN (N'nvarchar', N'nchar')
                                                                THEN CAST(c.max_length / 2 AS nvarchar(20))
                                                            ELSE CAST(c.max_length AS nvarchar(20))
                                                       END
                                             END + N') COLLATE ' + @DatabaseCollation
                  END + CASE WHEN c.is_nullable = 1 THEN N' NULL;' ELSE N' NOT NULL;' END
    FROM        sys.columns AS c
    INNER JOIN  sys.types   AS ty
       ON       ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
       AND      ty.name           <> N'sysname'
    WHERE       c.object_id = @object_id
    AND         c.collation_name    <> @DatabaseCollation;
    
    /************************************************************************************************************************************
    *   If the table has affected indexes, this creates the drop and recreate index scripts                                             *
    ************************************************************************************************************************************/
    IF @has_index > 0
    BEGIN;
        -- Process indexes on affected columns, one by one
        DECLARE CursorIndex CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY READ_ONLY STATIC FOR
        SELECT  ix.index_id,
                ix.name,
                CASE WHEN ix.is_unique = 1 THEN N'UNIQUE ' ELSE N'' END,
                ix.type_desc,
                ix.filter_definition,
                CASE WHEN ix.is_padded = 1
                         THEN N'PAD_INDEX = ON, '
                     ELSE N'PAD_INDEX = OFF, '
                END + CASE WHEN ix.allow_page_locks = 1
                               THEN N'ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, '
                           ELSE N'ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = OFF, '
                      END + CASE WHEN ix.allow_row_locks = 1
                                     THEN N'ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, '
                                 ELSE N'ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = OFF, '
                            END + CASE WHEN INDEXPROPERTY(ix.object_id, ix.name, 'IsStatistics') = 1
                                           THEN N'STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = ON, '
                                       ELSE N'STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, '
                                  END + CASE WHEN ix.ignore_dup_key = 1
                                                 THEN N'IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON, '
                                             ELSE N'IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, '
                                        END + N'SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, FILLFACTOR ='
                + CASE WHEN ix.fill_factor = 0
                           THEN CAST(100 AS nvarchar(3))
                       ELSE CAST(ix.fill_factor AS nvarchar(3))
                  END                            AS IndexOptions,
                ix.is_disabled,
                FILEGROUP_NAME(ix.data_space_id) AS FileGroupName
        FROM    sys.indexes AS ix
        WHERE   ix.object_id        = @object_id
        AND     ix.type                 <> 0 -- Exclude heaps
        AND     ix.is_primary_key       = 0 -- Exclude primary key constraints (handled separately)
        AND     ix.is_unique_constraint = 0 -- Exclude unique constraints (handled separately)
        AND     EXISTS (SELECT      *   -- Has to constrain at least one column with wrong collation
                        FROM        sys.index_columns AS ic
                        INNER JOIN  sys.columns       AS c
                           ON       c.object_id       = ic.object_id
                           AND      c.column_id       = ic.column_id
                           AND      c.collation_name  <> @DatabaseCollation
                        INNER JOIN  sys.types         AS ty
                           ON       ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
                           AND      ty.name           <> N'sysname'
                        WHERE       ic.index_id = ix.index_id
                        AND         ic.object_id        = ix.object_id);
    
        OPEN CursorIndex;
        FETCH NEXT FROM CursorIndex
        INTO @index_id,
             @IndexName,
             @is_unique,
             @IndexTypeDesc,
             @filter_definition,
             @IndexOptions,
             @is_disabled,
             @FileGroupName;
    
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN;
            -- For each index, use a nested cursor to build lists of indexed and inclued columns
            SET @IndexColumns = N'';
            SET @IncludedColumns = N'';
    
            DECLARE CursorIndexColumn CURSOR FOR
            SELECT      c.name,
                        ic.is_descending_key,
                        ic.is_included_column
            FROM        sys.index_columns AS ic
            INNER JOIN  sys.columns       AS c
               ON       c.object_id = ic.object_id
               AND      c.column_id = ic.column_id
            WHERE       ic.object_id = @object_id
            AND         ic.index_id          = @index_id
            ORDER BY    ic.index_column_id;
    
            OPEN CursorIndexColumn;
            FETCH NEXT FROM CursorIndexColumn
            INTO @ColumnName,
                 @IsDescendingKey,
                 @IsIncludedColumn;
    
            WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
            BEGIN;
                IF @IsIncludedColumn = 0
                    SET @IndexColumns += QUOTENAME(@ColumnName)
                                         + CASE WHEN @IsDescendingKey = 1 THEN N' DESC, ' ELSE N' ASC, ' END;
                ELSE
                    SET @IncludedColumns += QUOTENAME(@ColumnName) + N', ';
    
                FETCH NEXT FROM CursorIndexColumn
                INTO @ColumnName,
                     @IsDescendingKey,
                     @IsIncludedColumn;
            END;
    
            CLOSE CursorIndexColumn;
            DEALLOCATE CursorIndexColumn;
    
            -- Remove trailing comma
            SET @IndexColumns = SUBSTRING(@IndexColumns, 1, LEN(@IndexColumns) - 1);
            IF @IncludedColumns <> N''
                SET @IncludedColumns = SUBSTRING(@IncludedColumns, 1, LEN(@IncludedColumns) - 1);
    
            -- Generate DROP INDEX statement
            INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                          script)
            SELECT  'DropIndex',
                    N'DROP INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + '.' + QUOTENAME(@IndexName)
                    + N';';
    
            -- Generate CREATE INDEX statement
            INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                          script)
            SELECT  'CreateIndex',
                    N'CREATE ' + @is_unique + @IndexTypeDesc + N' INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(@IndexName) + N' ON '
                    + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N'(' + @IndexColumns + N') '
                    + CASE WHEN @IncludedColumns <> N''
                               THEN N'INCLUDE (' + @IncludedColumns + N')'
                           ELSE N''
                      END 
                    + CASE WHEN @filter_definition <> '' 
                                THEN N' WHERE ' + @filter_definition ELSE '' 
                      END 
                    + N' WITH (' + @IndexOptions + N') ON ' + QUOTENAME(@FileGroupName) + N';';
            -- Generate script to (re)disable disabled index after creating it
            IF @is_disabled = 1
                INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                              script)
                SELECT  'DisableIndex',
                        N'ALTER INDEX ' + QUOTENAME(@IndexName) + N' ON ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.'
                        + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' DISABLE;';
    
            FETCH NEXT FROM CursorIndex
            INTO @index_id,
                 @IndexName,
                 @is_unique,
                 @IndexTypeDesc,
                 @filter_definition,
                 @IndexOptions,
                 @is_disabled,
                 @FileGroupName;
        END;
    
        CLOSE CursorIndex;
        DEALLOCATE CursorIndex;
    END;
    
    /************************************************************************************************************************************
    *   If the table has an affected primary key constraint, this creates the drop and recreate constraint script                       *
    *   this has been taken and adapted from a script found online created by Jayakumaur R                                              *
    ************************************************************************************************************************************/
    IF @has_key_constraint > 0
    BEGIN;
        -- Find columns and other metadata for primary key
        SELECT      kc.object_id                                                                          AS constid,
                    kc.name                                                                               AS constraint_name,   -- PK name
                    QUOTENAME(c.name) + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN N' DESC' ELSE N' ASC' END AS pk_col,
                    ic.key_ordinal,
                    i.name                                                                                AS index_name,
                    i.type_desc                                                                           AS index_type,
                    QUOTENAME(fg.name)                                                                    AS filegroup_name,
                    N' WITH (PAD_INDEX = ' + CASE WHEN i.is_padded = 0 THEN N'OFF' ELSE N'ON' END + N', IGNORE_DUP_KEY = '
                    + CASE WHEN i.ignore_dup_key = 0 THEN N'OFF' ELSE N'ON' END + N', ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = '
                    + CASE WHEN i.allow_row_locks = 0 THEN N'OFF' ELSE N'ON' END + ', ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = '
                    + CASE WHEN i.allow_page_locks = 0 THEN N'OFF)' ELSE N'ON)' END                       AS index_property
        INTO        #temp_pk
        FROM        sys.key_constraints AS kc
        INNER JOIN  sys.indexes         AS i
           ON       i.object_id      = kc.parent_object_id
           AND      i.is_primary_key = 1
        INNER JOIN  sys.index_columns   AS ic
           ON       ic.object_id     = i.object_id
           AND      ic.index_id      = i.index_id
        INNER JOIN  sys.columns         AS c
           ON       c.object_id      = ic.object_id
           AND      c.column_id      = ic.column_id
        INNER JOIN  sys.filegroups      AS fg
           ON       fg.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
        WHERE       kc.type     = 'PK'
        AND         kc.parent_object_id = @object_id;
    
        -- Generate DROP CONSTRAINT statement
        INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                      script)
        SELECT  TOP (1) -- One DROP statement, even if there are multiple columns
                'DropPrimaryKey',
                N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' DROP CONSTRAINT '
                + QUOTENAME(constraint_name) + N';'
        FROM    #temp_pk;
    
        -- Generate CREATE CONSTRAINT statement
        INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                      script)
        SELECT  TOP (1) -- One CREATE statement, even if there are multiple columns
                'AddPrimaryKey',
                N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' ADD CONSTRAINT '
                + QUOTENAME(p.constraint_name) + N' PRIMARY KEY ' + CAST(p.index_type AS nvarchar(100)) + N' ('
                + STUFF((SELECT     N', ' + pk_col  -- This generates a comma-separated list of the columns, in order
                         FROM       #temp_pk
                         ORDER BY   key_ordinal
                        FOR XML PATH('')),
                        1,
                        2,
                        N'') + N')' + p.index_property + N' ON ' + p.filegroup_name + N';'
        FROM    #temp_pk AS p;
    
        DROP TABLE #temp_pk;
    END;
```

Comment: Why did you post these as two separate answers? Why not [edit] them into a single answer? Or are they intended as two distinct solutions? Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Part two

> Note: This is not my solution, it is a compilation comments posts that worked for me from this url https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2019/01/collation-change-script/.

```
    /************************************************************************************************************************************
    *   If the table has a foreign key constraint on an affected column, this creates the drop and recreate constraint script           *
    *   this has been taken and adapted from a script found online cretaed by Jayakumaur R                                              *
    ************************************************************************************************************************************/
    IF @has_foreign_key > 0
    BEGIN;
        -- Process foreign key constraints on affected columns, one by one
        DECLARE foreignkeycursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT  fk.object_id,
                fk.name
        FROM    sys.foreign_keys AS fk
        WHERE   fk.parent_object_id = @object_id
        AND     EXISTS (SELECT      *   -- Has to constrain at least one column with wrong collation
                        FROM        sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc
                        INNER JOIN  sys.columns             AS c
                           ON       c.object_id       = fkc.parent_object_id
                           AND      c.column_id       = fkc.parent_column_id
                           AND      c.collation_name  <> @DatabaseCollation
                        INNER JOIN  sys.types               AS ty
                           ON       ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
                           AND      ty.name           <> N'sysname'
                        WHERE       fkc.parent_object_id = fk.parent_object_id
                        AND         fkc.constraint_object_id     = fk.object_id);
    
        OPEN foreignkeycursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM foreignkeycursor
        INTO @FK_objectid,
             @FK_name;
    
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN;
            -- Find columns and other metadata for foreign key
            SELECT      fk.object_id                                      AS constid,
                        fk.name                                           AS constraint_name,   -- FK name
                        fkc.constraint_column_id                          AS column_ordinal,
                        QUOTENAME(c1.name)                                AS key_col,
                        QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id)) + N'.'
                        + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(fk.referenced_object_id)) AS ref_table,
                        QUOTENAME(c2.name)                                AS ref_col,
                        CASE WHEN fk.delete_referential_action <> 0 -- No action
                                 THEN N' ON DELETE ' + fk.delete_referential_action_desc
                             ELSE N''
                        END                                               AS delete_cascade,
                        CASE WHEN fk.update_referential_action <> 0 -- No action
                                 THEN N' ON UPDATE ' + fk.update_referential_action_desc
                             ELSE N''
                        END                                               AS update_cascade,
                        fk.is_not_trusted,
                        fk.is_disabled
            INTO        #temp_fk
            FROM        sys.foreign_keys        AS fk
            INNER JOIN  sys.foreign_key_columns AS fkc
               ON       fkc.parent_object_id     = fk.parent_object_id
               AND      fkc.constraint_object_id = fk.object_id
            INNER JOIN  sys.columns             AS c1
               ON       c1.object_id             = fkc.parent_object_id
               AND      c1.column_id             = fkc.parent_column_id
            INNER JOIN  sys.columns             AS c2
               ON       c2.object_id             = fkc.referenced_object_id
               AND      c2.column_id             = fkc.referenced_column_id
            WHERE       fk.object_id = @FK_objectid;
    
            -- Generate DROP CONSTRAINT statement
            INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                          script)
            SELECT  'DropForeignKey',
                    N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' DROP CONSTRAINT '
                    + QUOTENAME(@FK_name) + N';';
    
            -- Generate CREATE CONSTRAINT statement (always as ënabled, "not trusted"; status is changed later in script)
            INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                          script)
            SELECT  TOP (1) -- One CREATE statement, even if there are multiple columns
                    'AddForeignKey',
                    N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
                    + N' WITH NOCHECK ADD CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(constraint_name) + N' FOREIGN KEY ('
                    + STUFF(
                      (SELECT       N', ' + key_col -- This generates a comma-separated list of the constrained columns, in order
                       FROM         #temp_fk
                       ORDER BY     column_ordinal
                      FOR XML PATH('')),
                      1,
                      2,
                      N'') + N') REFERENCES ' + ref_table + N'('
                    + STUFF(
                      (SELECT       N', ' + ref_col -- This generates a comma-separated list of the referencedcolumns, in order
                       FROM         #temp_fk
                       ORDER BY     column_ordinal
                      FOR XML PATH('')),
                      1,
                      2,
                      N'') + N')' + delete_cascade + update_cascade + ';'
            FROM    #temp_fk;
    
            -- If constraint was disabled, add code to disable it again
            INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                          script)
            SELECT  TOP (1) -- One CREATE statement, even if there are multiple columns
                    'DisableForeignKey',
                    N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' NOCHECK CONSTRAINT '
                    + QUOTENAME(constraint_name) + N';'
            FROM    #temp_fk
            WHERE   is_disabled = 1;
    
            -- If constraint was trusted, add code to force re-check so it's trudsted again
            INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                          script)
            SELECT  TOP (1) -- One CREATE statement, even if there are multiple columns
                    'CheckForeignKey',
                    N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName)
                    + N' WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT ' + QUOTENAME(constraint_name) + N';'
            FROM    #temp_fk
            WHERE   is_not_trusted = 0;
    
            DROP TABLE #temp_fk;
    
            FETCH NEXT FROM foreignkeycursor
            INTO @FK_objectid,
                 @FK_name;
        END;
        CLOSE foreignkeycursor;
        DEALLOCATE foreignkeycursor;
    END;
    
    /*comment code 
    -- DROP and CREATE statistics for manual statistics has been disabled for now
    /************************************************************************************************************************************
    * If the column has statistics that aren't part of an index this creates the drop and recreate scripts *
    ************************************************************************************************************************************/
    IF @has_stats > 0
    AND @has_index = 0
    BEGIN
    DECLARE stats_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT sc.stats_id
    FROM sys.stats_columns AS sc
    JOIN sys.stats AS s
    ON s.object_id = sc.object_id
    AND s.stats_id = sc.stats_id
    AND s.user_created = 1
    WHERE sc.object_id = @object_id
    AND sc.column_id = @Collation_columnid;
    OPEN stats_cursor;
    FETCH NEXT FROM stats_cursor
    INTO @stats_id;
    WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
    BEGIN
    –Create DROP Statistics Statement
    INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore
    (ScriptType,
    script)
    SELECT 'DropStatistics',
    'DROP STATISTICS ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(s.object_id)) + '.'
    + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(s.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(s.name)
    FROM sys.stats AS s
    WHERE s.object_id = @object_id
    AND s.stats_id = @stats_id;
    
            --Building the CREATE statistics statement
    
            --Obtaining all the information
            SELECT  QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(sc.object_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(sc.object_id)) AS st_table,
                    QUOTENAME(s.name)                                                                        AS st_name,
                    QUOTENAME(c.name)                                                                        AS st_column,
                    sc.object_id,
                    sc.stats_id,
                    sc.stats_column_id
            INTO    #temp_stats
            FROM    sys.stats_columns AS sc
            JOIN    sys.stats         AS s
              ON    s.stats_id  = sc.stats_id
              AND   s.object_id = sc.object_id
            JOIN    sys.columns       AS c
              ON    c.object_id = sc.object_id
              AND   c.column_id = sc.column_id
            WHERE   sc.object_id = @object_id
            AND     sc.stats_id      = @stats_id;
            WITH
            cte AS
                (SELECT DISTINCT ts.st_table,
                                 ts.st_name,
                                 SUBSTRING((SELECT      ',' + st_column
                                            FROM        #temp_stats
                                            WHERE       stats_id = ts.stats_id
                                            ORDER BY    stats_column_id ASC
                                           FOR XML PATH('')),
                                           2,
                                           99999) AS st_col_list
                 FROM   #temp_stats AS ts)
            --Constructing the statement
            INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore
                (ScriptType,
                 script)
            SELECT  'AddStatistics',
                    'CREATE STATISTICS ' + cte.st_name + ' ON ' + cte.st_table + '(' + cte.st_col_list + ')'
            FROM    cte;
            DROP TABLE #temp_stats;
            FETCH NEXT FROM stats_cursor
            INTO @stats_id;
        END;
        CLOSE stats_cursor;
        DEALLOCATE stats_cursor;
    END;
    */
    
    /************************************************************************************************************************************
    *   If the table has unique constraints on affected columns, this creates the drop and recreate scripts                             *
    ************************************************************************************************************************************/
    
    IF @has_unique_constraint > 0
    BEGIN;
        -- Process unique constraints on affected columns, one by one
        DECLARE uniquecursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT  kc.object_id,
                kc.name,
                kc.unique_index_id
        FROM    sys.key_constraints AS kc
        WHERE   kc.parent_object_id = @object_id
        AND     kc.type                 = 'UQ'
        AND     EXISTS (SELECT      *   -- Has to constrain at least one column with wrong collation
                        FROM        sys.index_columns AS ic
                        INNER JOIN  sys.columns       AS c
                           ON       c.object_id       = ic.object_id
                           AND      c.column_id       = ic.column_id
                           AND      c.collation_name  <> @DatabaseCollation
                        INNER JOIN  sys.types         AS ty
                           ON       ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
                           AND      ty.name           <> N'sysname'
                        WHERE       ic.object_id = kc.parent_object_id
                        AND         ic.index_id          = kc.unique_index_id);
    
        OPEN uniquecursor;
        FETCH NEXT FROM uniquecursor
        INTO @UQ_objectid,
             @UQ_name,
             @UQ_index_id;
    
        WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)
        BEGIN;
            -- Find columns and other metadata for unique constraint
            SELECT      QUOTENAME(c.name) + CASE WHEN ic.is_descending_key = 1 THEN N' DESC' ELSE N' ASC' END     AS uq_col,
                        ic.key_ordinal,
                        i.name                                                                                    AS index_name,
                        i.type_desc                                                                               AS index_type,
                        QUOTENAME(fg.name)                                                                        AS filegroup_name,
                        N' WITH (PAD_INDEX = ' + CASE WHEN i.is_padded = 0 THEN N'OFF' ELSE N'ON' END
                        + N', IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ' + CASE WHEN i.ignore_dup_key = 0 THEN N'OFF' ELSE N'ON' END
                        + N', ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ' + CASE WHEN i.allow_row_locks = 0 THEN N'OFF' ELSE N'ON' END
                        + ', ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ' + CASE WHEN i.allow_page_locks = 0 THEN N'OFF)' ELSE N'ON)' END AS index_property
            INTO        #temp_uq
            FROM        sys.indexes       AS i
            INNER JOIN  sys.index_columns AS ic
               ON       ic.object_id     = i.object_id
               AND      ic.index_id      = i.index_id
            INNER JOIN  sys.columns       AS c
               ON       c.object_id      = ic.object_id
               AND      c.column_id      = ic.column_id
            INNER JOIN  sys.filegroups    AS fg
               ON       fg.data_space_id = i.data_space_id
            WHERE       i.object_id    = @object_id
            AND         i.index_id             = @UQ_index_id
            AND         i.is_unique_constraint = 1;
    
            -- Generate DROP CONSTRAINT statement
            INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                          script)
            SELECT  'DropUniqueKey',
                    N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' DROP CONSTRAINT '
                    + QUOTENAME(@UQ_name) + N';';
    
            -- Generate CREATE CONSTRAINT statement
            INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                          script)
            SELECT  TOP (1) -- One CREATE statement, even if there are multiple columns
                    'AddUniqueKey',
                    N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' ADD CONSTRAINT '
                    + QUOTENAME(@UQ_name) + N' UNIQUE ' + CAST(index_type AS nvarchar(100)) + N' ('
                    + STUFF((SELECT     N', ' + uq_col  -- This generates a comma-separated list of the columns, in order
                             FROM       #temp_uq
                             ORDER BY   key_ordinal
                            FOR XML PATH('')),
                            1,
                            2,
                            N'') + N')' + index_property + N' ON ' + filegroup_name + N';'
            FROM    #temp_uq;
    
            DROP TABLE #temp_uq;
    
            FETCH NEXT FROM uniquecursor
            INTO @UQ_objectid,
                 @UQ_name,
                 @UQ_index_id;
        END;
        CLOSE uniquecursor;
        DEALLOCATE uniquecursor;
    END;
    
    
    /************************************************************************************************************************************
    *  If the table has default constraints on affected columns, this creates the drop and recreate scripts in the table                *
    ************************************************************************************************************************************/
    IF @has_default_constraint > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                      script)
        SELECT      'DropDefault',
                    N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' DROP CONSTRAINT '
                    + QUOTENAME(dc.name) + ' '
        FROM        sys.columns AS c 
        INNER JOIN  sys.default_constraints dc 
           ON       dc.object_id = c.default_object_id 
           AND      dc.parent_column_id = c.column_id 
        INNER JOIN  sys.types   AS ty
           ON       ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
           AND      ty.name           <> N'sysname'
        WHERE       c.object_id = @object_id
        AND         c.collation_name    <> @DatabaseCollation;
    
    
        INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                      script)
        SELECT      'CreateDefault',
                    N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' ADD DEFAULT '
                    + dc.definition + ' FOR ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) 
        FROM        sys.columns AS c 
        INNER JOIN  sys.default_constraints dc on dc.object_id = c.default_object_id 
        INNER JOIN  sys.types   AS ty
           ON       ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
           AND      ty.name           <> N'sysname'
        WHERE       c.object_id = @object_id
        AND         c.collation_name    <> @DatabaseCollation;
    End
    
    /************************************************************************************************************************************
    * If the table has check constraints on affected columns, this creates the drop and recreate scripts in the table *
    ************************************************************************************************************************************/
    IF @has_check_constraint > 0
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                        script)
        SELECT 'DropCheck',
        N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' DROP CONSTRAINT '
        + QUOTENAME(cc.name) + ' '
        FROM sys.columns AS c
        INNER JOIN sys.check_constraints cc
        ON c.object_id = cc.parent_object_id
        AND cc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
        INNER JOIN sys.types AS ty
        ON ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
        AND ty.name <> N'sysname'
        WHERE c.object_id = @object_id
        AND c.collation_name <> @DatabaseCollation;
    
        INSERT INTO #tempscriptstore (ScriptType,
                                      script)
        SELECT      'CreateCheck',
                    N'ALTER TABLE ' + QUOTENAME(@SchemaName) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(@TableName) + N' WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT '
                    + QUOTENAME(cc.name) + ' CHECK ' + cc.definition 
        FROM        sys.columns AS c 
        INNER JOIN  sys.check_constraints cc 
            ON      cc.parent_object_id = c.object_id
            AND     cc.parent_column_id = c.column_id
        INNER JOIN  sys.types   AS ty
           ON       ty.system_type_id = c.system_type_id
           AND      ty.name           <> N'sysname'
        WHERE       c.object_id = @object_id
        AND         c.collation_name    <> @DatabaseCollation
        group by    cc.name, cc.definition;
    end
    
    
    FETCH NEXT FROM collationfix
    INTO @object_id,
         @SchemaName,
         @TableName,
         @has_key_constraint,
         @has_index,
         @has_foreign_key,
         @has_stats,
         @has_unique_constraint,
         @has_default_constraint,
         @has_check_constraint;
    END;
    CLOSE collationfix;
    DEALLOCATE collationfix;
    
    /************************************************************************************************************************************
    * Returns all the created scripts in the correct order for running *
    * Also add GO in between some sections so the entire script can execute at once *
    ************************************************************************************************************************************/
    DECLARE @oddnum INT = 1;
    WITH ScriptInput
    AS (SELECT script,
    CASE WHEN ScriptType = 'DropDefault'
    THEN 1
    WHEN ScriptType = 'DropForeignKey'
    THEN 3
    WHEN ScriptType = 'DropIndex'
    THEN 5
    WHEN ScriptType = 'DropUniqueKey'
    THEN 7
    WHEN ScriptType = 'DropPrimaryKey'
    THEN 9
    WHEN ScriptType = 'DropStatistics'
    THEN 11
    WHEN ScriptType = 'DropCheck'
    THEN 13
    WHEN ScriptType = 'AlterCollation'
    THEN 15
    WHEN ScriptType = 'AddPrimaryKey'
    THEN 17
    WHEN ScriptType = 'AddUniqueKey'
    THEN 19
    WHEN ScriptType = 'CreateIndex'
    THEN 21
    WHEN ScriptType = 'AddStatistics'
    THEN 23
    WHEN ScriptType = 'AddForeignKey'
    THEN 25
    WHEN ScriptType = 'DisableForeignKey'
    THEN 27
    WHEN ScriptType = 'CheckForeignKey'
    THEN 29
    WHEN ScriptType = 'DisableIndex'
    THEN 31
    WHEN ScriptType = 'CreateDefault'
    THEN 33
    WHEN ScriptType = 'CreateCheck'
    THEN 35
    ELSE 99
    END AS SortOrder
    
    FROM #tempscriptstore
    UNION ALL
    SELECT CASE WHEN n.num > 0
    THEN 'GO' + CHAR(13)+CHAR(10) + descrip
    ELSE descrip end,
    n.num
    FROM (VALUES (0, '--- Drop Default'),
    (2, '--- Drop Foreign Key'),
    (4, '--- Drop Index'),
    (6, '--- Drop Unique Key'),
    (8, '--- Drop Primary Key'),
    --(10, '--- Drop Statistics'),
    (12, '--- Drop Check '),
    (14, '--- Alter Collation '),
    (16, '--- Add Primary Key '),
    (18, '--- Add Unique Key '),
    (20, '--- Create Index '),
    --(22, '--- Add Statistics '),
    (24, '--- Add Foreign Key '),
    (26, '--- Disable Foreign Key '),
    (28, '--- Check Foreign Key '),
    (30, '--- Disable Index '),
    (32, '--- Create Default '),
    (34, '--- Create Check '),
    (36, '--- End of script')
    ) AS n (num, descrip) )
    SELECT ScriptInput.script
    FROM ScriptInput
    ORDER BY ScriptInput.SortOrder;
    
    DROP TABLE #tempscriptstore;
```