# Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Arabic_CI_AS" in the equal to operation

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

https://d.top4top.net/p_816jaa4d1.png

I Need Help Please Problem In Link Image...

Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and "Arabic_CI_AS" in the equal to operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be better, if you post SQL as a plain text rather than image.

In your case, the issue is in different collations in columns you match in a query. The universal workaround is:

```
WHERE IFG.ITEM_NAME = I.ITEM_NAME COLLATE database_default
```

However, consider to make all columns in a database matched to the same collation, collations can be checked this way:

```
SELECT 
    t.Name 'Table Name',
    c.name 'Col Name',
    c.collation_name
FROM     sys.columns c 
INNER JOIN     sys.tables t ON c.object_id = t.object_id
INNER JOIN     sys.types ty ON c.system_type_id = ty.system_type_id    
WHERE     t.is_ms_shipped = 0
```

It can be done [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18122773/change-collations-of-all-columns-of-all-tables-in-sql-server)