# Collation conflict within the same database

Tags: sql, sql-server, union, collate

I perform a union on two queries. Simplified version looks like this:

```sql
select * from Audit.dbo.PolicyList_t pl
union
select * from Audit.dbo.PolicyList_CurrencyFlip_t pl
```

Both tables are in the same database. However, I get the following error:

```
Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "Latin1_General_CI_AS" and "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" in the UNION operation.
```

I would expect the collation error when operating on different databases not when querying two tables in the same database.

I checked the properties of both tables and in both cases, the collation is `Latin1_General_CI_AS`. However, when both selects address the same table I don't get any errors. Obviously, when running separately, both selects work.

I'm on SQL Server. Any suggestion what can be the source of the issue?

Comment: Collation can be per column. Check your columns.

Comment: Which db server are you running, SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, SQL Serve. I'm adding that to my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In [SQL Server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx), at least, collation can be applied per column.  So I'd check that.

You might find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730114/how-to-change-the-collate-to-all-the-columns-of-the-database) about setting all columns to the same collation to be useful.