# SQL_Latin1_General error

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have created the `.bak` file from my local database (MSSQL SERVER 2012) and restored it on live server (MSSQL Server 2012). It is working but some the `stored_procedures` are not executing and are generating error:

> **Cannot resolve the collation conflict between 
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" and 
>   "Latin1_General_CI_AI" 
>   in the equal to operation**

I do not have any idea what this error is and how to resolve it?

I have thousands of stored_procedures.How to resolve this issue in all stored procedures?

Comment: This is probably compatibility versions. for now you can look up 'COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT' and use this in your query or you can fix the compatibility version so that they match.

Comment: Do I have to do it every problematic `stored_procedure`?

Comment: If you want to do it at a query level, yes. Otherwise just change the compatibility mode to match what it was before.

Comment: how can I change compatibility mode? I think it will be better than changing 1000 of procedures.

Comment: @Dev [Set or Change the Database Collation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms175835(v=sql.110).aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve the collation conflict between "SQL\_Latin1\_General\_CP1\_CI\_AS" and "Latin1\_General\_CI\_AS" in the equal to operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1607560/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between-sql-latin1-general-cp1-ci-as-and)

Comment: @ChrisPickford ,WIll it work for all stored_procedures?I am new to these type of advanced settings.

Comment: These settings will change it for everything, use the link @ChrisPickford posted.

Comment: @RichBenner, it dodn't worked `ALTER DATABASE myDBName
COLLATE collatename ;` procedure still generating error

Comment: You appear to be linking two databases that are using a different collation method. Make sure they're both set to the same. Also, I'd speak to your DBA about this. You do have a DBA don't you?

Comment: @RichBenner, don't have a DBA.

Comment: @Dev google 'Brent Ozar Accidental DBA' and sign up to the emails, they're really useful and should help your skills. Looks like you're the DBA now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot resolve the collation conflict between](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616620/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between)

Answer (score 2):

The issue is likely to be a difference in collation settings between your "local" SQL Server and your "live" SQL Server and as a result the wrong collation being used by your database and database objects.

You need to pay close attention to server parameters (ANSI settings, Collation etc) when installing a development server to ensure they fully match your production server. The same applies to the database parameters. [See this somewhat old but still relevant article](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174903(v=sql.80).aspx) about how collation settings work.

You can find out the current collation settings either through SSMS or by running the following queries (see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/hh230914.aspx)):

```
-- Server Collation Setting
SELECT CONVERT (varchar, SERVERPROPERTY('collation'));

-- Database Collation Settings
SELECT name, collation_name FROM sys.databases;

-- Table column Collation Settings
SELECT t.name, c.name AS ColName, *
FROM sys.tables AS t
    INNER JOIN sys.columns AS c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE not collation_name is NULL
ORDER BY t.name, column_id
```

You have two choices in how to resolve this:

### Change collation setting of your database and all objects

To resolve this collation difference on the "live" environament you will need to:
 1. [Change collation of your database](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms175835.aspx) to match the collation setting of the production server
 2. Change collation of every column in your tables / views etc (see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16730114/how-to-change-the-collate-to-all-the-columns-of-the-database))

The easiest solution is to just recreate every single object in the database (after you change DB collation) with the correct collation setting.

### Modify your code

The 2nd option is what people have suggested in comments, namelly explicitly specify collation setting "everywhere" in your code. This option should be used as a last resort or when absoluely necessary (cannot think of a reason when this may be necessary).

### Miscellaneous

It is also possible to [change collation of the server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms179254.aspx) but this is not really an option.

Comment: plus1 for a good answer - however Option 2 - imho - should be avoided!

Comment: @BIDeveloper, thanks for feedback; answer has been edited.