# Why collation problem when database and SQL query use the same?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have SQL Server 2014 Express edition installed on a Portuguese Windows 10 computer. I have a database that was created on an US computer. I have changed the collation of the database in SSMS. I examine tables, stored procedures, etc and they all have the default collation of SQL Server (`Latin1_General_CI_CA`).

When I try to execute a stored procedure in the database, SQL Server barfs up a collation mismatch between `Latin1_General_CI_AS` and `SQL_Latin1_CP1_CI_AS`. I have checked everything that I know of and the collation matches.

Really hoping to avoid rewriting all my stored procedures to set the default collation.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17616620/cannot-resolve-the-collation-conflict-between might be helpful.

Comment: The linked answer will provide very helpful information. Additionally be aware of the temp tables collation, which is the server's collation by default. If you create a `#tbl` with a string column and use this against one of your table's columns, that's one more sink for collation errors. If ever possible it is best to keep server's collation, database collation and all object's collation in sync...