# Setting collation to case insensitive not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to change the collation in my sql database so that it would be case insensitive with no success. What I have it set to currently is this: "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" which is supposed to be case insensitive yet it is case sensitive.

Which collation I need to pick ?

Thanks

Comment: I run a simple query like: select * from Countries where Country = 'usa'

Comment: Changing collation on DB level affects newly created objects. Existing fields keep their original collation.

Comment: is there a way I could force that change onto my old objects?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update Collation of all fields in database on the fly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878430/update-collation-of-all-fields-in-database-on-the-fly)

Comment: A mass collation change of existing columns is not trivial because one must first drop constraints and indexes on the columns to be changed and recreate afterward.  Tools like SSDT and Red-Gate SQL Compare can facilitate this.  You could also create a new database with the desired column collation side-by-side and transfer data from old to new.